# Relative completion of a cocomplete category

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am looking for a construction of the relative completion of a category. This is described but not contructed in Joyal's [Free Bicomplete Categories](https://mr.math.ca/article/free-bicomplete-categories/). Given a cocomplete category $\mathcal{C}$, the relative completion $\Lambda^{\pi}\mathcal{C}$, is a category with a cocontinuous functor $j : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \Lambda^{\pi}\mathcal{C}$, such that any cocontinuous functor $F$ into a bicomplete category $\mathcal{D}$ extends uniquely to a bicontinuous functor $F' \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ such that $F' \circ j \cong F$. This construction can be used to construct the bicompletion of a category which is my main motivation for the question.

Joyal's paper claims that there is some sort of construction based on presheaves and that the functor $j$ is fully faithful. There is a construction of the bicompletion in a different [mathoverflow question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686774/can-we-simultaneously-freely-adjoin-both-limits-and-colimits-to-a-category), but it isn't clear from this construction why the functor $j$ should be fully faithful.